# Upload a file on local server and share a link with others to download

Tags: download, web, storage, upload, links

I want to share a link with others (friends, family) which will enable them to download a file from my home-based server. The link should be generated each time I choose a specific file to share, therefore the link must be somehow different for each download session (similar way Dropbox shares public links).

So basically, what I'm asking is a web-based software (preferably open source and hosted locally) which will allow me to store locally a specific file and then somehow generate a link which I can share with a person to download.

Does anyone know anything similar with this? I've tried but I didn't manage to find something like this. Do I have to implement myself a custom made web-based application?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUSer. Shopping questions are off topic and this will likley be voted closed.  Please check the FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific product recommendations are off-topic for SU.

However *any* webserver run on your home based server will do.

No need to link the file to a webpage. Just 'upload' it to your home server webdir, test the URL and copy that into the mail to your family.

E.g. use `http://croussou.com/shared_example.jpg` and mail that.

Answer (score 0):

See here for comparisons: <strike>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers</strike> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software

I've used [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) for quite some time and absolutely love it for quick file sharing.  Just remember that you will have to do some port forwarding of your router no matter which server program you go with.

Comment: True. If he uses NAT he will have to forward a port. But his profile already shows his webpage so I think that part is already taken care off.  Good link to wikipedia though.